# How can you change the default deployment properties?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-deployment

Our BizTalk Server got renamed, but when we create a new project it still keeps defaulting to the previous server. I have been looking but I can't find anywhere to set these default values and update it.

edit:

Since it might be more clear if I add an image, I did.

Basically now when a new project is created the Server in the below screen is BizTalkDev_1. Can we change this to always be localhost when we create a new project? A hidden ini file somewhere?

[image: image of what I want to default]

Answer (score 0):

When you go to visual studio project. Right click the project ...go to the property...and in the deployment part you can change the server name ...

Comment: this would require me to change this everytime i make a new project (since all new projects have the old pc name)